# Unable to publish an ASP.NET SignalR code

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr

I implemented a SignalR within a classic ASP.NET Web Forms to enable a progress bar. Everything works perfectly when testing the implementation locally

However, when I try to publish the code into a server, the application crashes showing an extremely generic ASP.NET error

Is there anything specific I have to use or do when publishing the SignalR?

Thank you very much in advance

Here is my Hub class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;

namespace IAACCESS.SignalR
{
    public class ProgressHub : Hub
    {
        static ProgressHub()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Here is my startup class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Owin;

[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(IAACCESS.SignalR.Startup1))]

namespace IAACCESS.SignalR
{
    public class Startup1
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.MapSignalR();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my JavaScript section

```
   function ProgressBarModal(showHide) {

        if (showHide === 'show') {
            $('#mod-progress').show();
            if (arguments.length >= 2) {
                $('#progressBarParagraph').text(arguments[1]);
            } else {
                $('#progressBarParagraph').text(arguments[1]);
            }

            window.progressBarActive = true;

        } else {
            $('#mod-progress').hide();
            window.progressBarActive = false;
        }
    }

    $(function () {
        // Reference the auto-generated proxy for the hub.
        var progress = $.connection.progressHub;
        console.log(progress);

        // Create a function that the hub can call back to display messages.
        progress.client.AddProgress = function (fileName, message, percentage) {
            ProgressBarModal("show", fileName + " " + message);
            document.getElementById("divProgress").style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById("divUpload").style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById("divProgress").style.width =  percentage + "%";
            document.getElementById("<%=lblPercentage.ClientID %>").firstChild.data = parseInt(percentage) +  "%";
            $('#ProgressMessage').width(percentage);
            if (percentage === "100%") {
                ProgressBarModal();
            }
        };

        $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
            var connectionId = $.connection.hub.id;
            console.log(connectionId);
        });

    });
```

Comment: What is the extremely generic error?

Comment: Runtime Error
Description: An exception occurred while processing your request. Additionally, another exception occurred while executing the custom error page for the first exception. The request has been terminated.

Comment: Actually, after I changed customerrors attribute to Off, I received another error saying 'Server Error in '/access_int' Application.

This operation requires IIS integrated pipeline mode

I did change the default pool to integrated and after that I received a message 

"500 - Internal server error.

There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed"

Please help

Comment: Have you checked Event Viewer on the server?  That might give you a better error or some stack trace information.

Comment: Guys, thank you for your help! I did resolve it, the explanation is below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, as I mentioned in the comments, I changed the custom error attribute from RemoteOnly to Off.

There I saw a better description of an error

> Server Error in '/access_int' Application. This operation requires IIS
>   integrated pipeline mode

I went to IIS, changed the application pool settings from Basic to Integrated

That gave me another error

> 500 - Internal server error. There is a problem with the resource you
>   are looking for, and it cannot be displayed

Then I went to IIS and changed property of identity impersonate to false

Everything worked after that